# DateTimeField.strftime() replaces the original value

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I have a ticket system, where I have tickets with following model:

```
state = models.IntegerField(default=1, choices=TICKET_STATES)
type = models.IntegerField(default=9, choices=TICKET_TYPE)
priority = models.IntegerField(default=2, choices=TICKET_PRIORITY)
heading = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Uusi tiketti')
description = models.TextField(default='')
date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
date_closed = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
created_by = models.ForeignKey(
    User,
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    null=True,
    related_name='tickets_created'
)
modified_by = models.ForeignKey(
    User,
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    null=True,
    related_name='tickets_modified'
)
closed_by = models.ForeignKey(
    User,
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    null=True,
    related_name='tickets_closed'
)
```

Now, I made a function that converts an instance to a dict, so I can pass it through API

```
def as_dict(self):
    data = model_to_dict(self)
    data['created_by'] = {
        'id' : self.created_by.id,
        'name' : self.created_by.full_name()
    }
    data['state'] = {
        'id' : self.state,
        'name' : self.get_state_display(),
        'color' : self.get_color()
    }
    data['priority'] = {
        'id' : self.priority,
        'name' : self.get_priority_display()
    }
    data['type'] = {
        'id' : self.type,
        'name' : self.get_type_display()
    }
    print(type(self))
    print(type(self.date_created))
    data['date_created'] = self.date_created.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    return data
```

However, issue is that if I then try to do anything, I get following complaint:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

This makes me think that strftime somehow converts the DateTimeField to str, but this should not be the case? Anyone have an idea what is happening here?

UPDATE

On the first pass, when everything works, print statements give:

```
<class 'ticket_service.models.Ticket'>
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

On the second pass, when the error happens (values have not been changed):

```
<class 'ticket_service.models.Ticket'>
<class 'str'>
```

Comment: What do the print lines show?

Comment: @TomHamiltonStubber Updated the question to include the print lines.

Answer (score 1):

Discovered the issue. In another function there was incorrect term for skipping the field, which accidentally stored a string. Correcting the typo fixed the issue.